# MediaSource canvas to video convertion with audio

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, webrtc, media-source

Hi Team i am new in the MediaSource related stuff.

question: The audio support for canvas streaming to video convertion using mediasource.

Details: I am trying to support audio support to video when canptering stream from the canvas using MediaSource.

code details:

```
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleSourceOpen, false);
let mediaRecorder;
let recordedBlobs;
let sourceBuffer;

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const video = document.querySelector('video');


function handleSourceOpen(event) {
  console.log('MediaSource opened');
  sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp8"');
  console.log('Source buffer: ', sourceBuffer);
}

function handleDataAvailable(event) {
  if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
  }
}

function handleStop(event) {
  console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
  const superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
}

function startRecording() {
  let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
  recordedBlobs = [];
  try {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
  } catch (e0) {
    console.log('Unable to create MediaRecorder with options Object: ', e0);
    try {
      options = {mimeType: 'video/webm,codecs=vp9'};
      mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    } catch (e1) {
      console.log('Unable to create MediaRecorder with options Object: ', e1);
      try {
        options = 'video/vp8'; // Chrome 47
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
      } catch (e2) {
        alert('MediaRecorder is not supported by this browser.\n\n' +
          'Try Firefox 29 or later, or Chrome 47 or later, ' +
          'with Enable experimental Web Platform features enabled from chrome://flags.');
        console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e2);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log('Created MediaRecorder', mediaRecorder, 'with options', options);
  recordButton.textContent = 'Stop Recording';
  mediaRecorder.onstop = handleStop;
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.start(100); // collect 100ms of data
  console.log('MediaRecorder started', mediaRecorder);
}

function stopRecording() {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
  console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', recordedBlobs);
  video.controls = true;
}

function play() {
  video.play();
}
```

In above code when you startdecording and do the any activity in canvan and stop the recording it will create video for video tag,but without audio i want to add audio as well, there any trick to solved this?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us where `stream` comes from, but I assume you're using the Canvas `captureStream`.  You also didn't explain where your audio comes from, but however you do it, you'll end up with a stream for that too.

What you need to do is take the tracks of the two streams and form another stream.  Something like this:

```
const stream = new MediaStream([
  ...canvasStream.getVideoTracks(),
  ...audioStream.getAudioTracks()
]);
```

Then, pass this new stream into your MediaRecorder.

Comment: yesterday i done this using add addTrack method. but thanks for your input